# pgfplots: "let \p1" command not working anymore inside axis environment, used to compile just fine

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I recently had some trouble with my MiKTeX distribution and reinstalled both MiKTeX and TeXstudio, having cleared any and all preferences, user settings, etc. on my machine. I was able to solve my problems, but for some strange reason, a tikzpicture which used to compile fine for the last 4(!) years is not working anymore. I've narrowed to problem down to the line in the following MWE which is using the "let \p1" command syntax (line 15):

```latex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \begin{axis}[tick style={color=black}, width=5cm, height=5cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=2e-4,
        ymin=0, ymax=2e-4,
        ticks=none]
            \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
            \coordinate (Rm) at (axis cs:1.5e-05,0);
            %
            \draw[very thin, fill=cyan] let \p1=($(Rm)-(O)$) in (axis cs:8.2902e-05,0.00017327) coordinate (M) circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
            \draw[->, red] (M) -- ++(axis cs:1.0607e-05,1.0607e-05) node[pos=0,below,inner sep=0,color=white] {\footnotesize{$r_m$}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now for the most curious thing: I've handed the MWE to a colleague whose installation is a few years old, he told me he last updated it probably more than a year ago. And with him it compiles just fine! I was not able to figure out what the difference between our two machines is, though, and changing the compatibility of `\pgfplotsset` does not seem to influence the compilation.

Here's my error output:

```
line 17: Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }. \end{axis}
line 17: Paragraph ended before \pgfmathfloatparse@@ was complete. \end{axis}
line 17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{axis}
line 17: Extra \else. \end{axis}
line 17: Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit part was near '-5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit part was near '-5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit part was near '-5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit part was near '-5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit part was near '-5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Missing number, treated as zero. \end{axis}
line 17: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit part was near '-5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{axis}
line 17: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitpart was near '5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitpart was near '5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitpart was near '5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitpart was near '5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitpart was near '5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Missing number, treated as zero. \end{axis}
line 17: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{axis}
line 17: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitpart was near '5.15831000000000'.. \end{axis}
line 17: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{axis}
line 17: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{axis}
line 17: Missing } inserted. \end{axis}
line 17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{axis}
line 17: Missing } inserted. \end{axis}
line 17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{axis}
line 17: Missing } inserted. \end{axis}
line 17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{axis}
line 17: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{axis}
line 18: Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Improper \prevdepth. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 18: Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
```

And my build command:

```
pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Comment: For the record: The "problem" was fixed in PGFPlots v1.17. Thus, your code works perfectly fine again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the deprecated syntax for circles, `circle(<radius>)`, but you are supposed to use `circle[radius=<radius>]`. Then there is no problem.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \begin{axis}[tick style={color=black}, width=5cm, height=5cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=2e-4,
        ymin=0, ymax=2e-4,
        ticks=none]
            \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
            \coordinate (Rm) at (axis cs:1.5e-05,0);
            %
            \draw[very thin, fill=cyan] let \p1=($(Rm)-(O)$) in (axis
            cs:8.2902e-05,0.00017327) coordinate (M) circle[radius={veclen(\x1,\y1)}];
            \draw[->, red] (M) -- ++(axis cs:1.0607e-05,1.0607e-05) node[pos=0,below,inner sep=0,color=white] {\footnotesize{$r_m$}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that [this issue has been reported](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/) but using the non-deprecated syntax also solves it.

Comment: That simple truth eluded me. Thank's so much!

Comment: @cschneeb You are welcome!